# ReactJs dynamic routing code spliting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I have router setup like this

```
<Router path="/" component={Application}>
 <Route path="/login" getComponent={(location, cb)=>{

      require.ensure([], function (require) {
                        cb(null, require('./components/Login').default);
                      });
}} />

 <Route path="/article/:articleid" getComponent={(location,cb)=>{
     require.ensure([], function (require) {
                        cb(null, require('./components/Article').default);
                      });
}}


</Router>
```

Now, the home page `/` loads, `/login` page loads with required chunk at `/0.chunk.js` but the `/article/some-article` page tries load required chunk `1.chunk.js` from `/article/1.chunk.js` which is not found.

Webpack generates all the chunks at one location `/0.chunk.js` and `/1.chunk.js`. Can somebody help why `/article/:articleid` is looking for the chunk at location `/article/` instead `/` and how to correct this. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are having relative path issues. You should make sure that the [`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath) is generating absolute paths.

```js
module.exports = {
  output: {
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  }
}
```